# Proving bipartition in a connected planar graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected planar graph with a planar embedding where every face boundary is a cycle of even length. Prove that $G$ is bipartite.

Any hints/tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go around the clock coloring, alternatively, the vertices black or white.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

- Every face has boundary of even length $\Rightarrow$ every simple cycle is of even length $\Rightarrow$ every cycle is of even length $\Rightarrow$ graph is bipartite.

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Sorry how did you go from every simple cycle is of even length to every cycle is of even length? I am a bit confused :\

Comment: @RobertMcDonald Every cycle is a xor of simple cycles.