# Face Boundary and bipartite question classification

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Is this question wrong?

Let G be a connected planar graph with a planar embedding where every face boundary is a cycle of even length. Prove that G is bipartite.

Consider a graph of 2 squares stacked on top of each other (7 edges, 6 vertices). It is connected, planar and every face boundary is a cycle of even length (4, 4, 6), but is not bipartite.

Comment: What makes you think that graph is not bipartite?

Comment: Because I couldnt find a partition such that all edges join vertices of one side to vertices of the other side.

Comment: Is there a trick to finding it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proving bipartition in a connected planar graph](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445331/proving-bipartition-in-a-connected-planar-graph)

Comment: @A_for_Abacus The graph is definitely bipartite. Try thinking about it this way: say that the squares are stacked vertically, and the top left vertex is in $A$. What does this tell you about the middle-left and top-right vertices?  What does this tell you about the bottom-left and middle-right?  Then the bottom-right?